# how much memory does node allocate for null values in arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, memory, null

Following up on this thread:

[Lots of null values in an array mean any harm?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4374627/lots-of-null-values-in-an-array-mean-any-harm)

I did this with node.js:

```
arr=[]
arr[1000]=1
arr[1000000000]=2
arr.sort()
```

And I got

```
FATAL ERROR: JS Allocation failed - process out of memory
```

So that leaves me with the question (I couldn't find it on Yahoogle) how much memory is actually allocated for a null entry in an array in node. I do not plan to use 1000000000 entries, not even close, but maybe it's still not worth allocating the memory...

Who knows how I can check?

Comment: Your program works fine for me in Node 0.6.2.

Comment: In my opinion, this has no dependence on node.js, but solely on the implementation of the JavaScript engine running the JavaScript as the question you references states.

Comment: Does it fail on `arr.sort()`?

Comment: For me it doesn't fail at all, and it doesn't use up hardly any memory.

Comment: The array contains `undefined` values, not `null` values.

Comment: Also it's quite important to note that those uninitialized array entries aren't `null` - they're `undefined`.  That means they don' exist.  They're really not allocated at all. (ha ha like @Eric sez.)

Comment: But isn't node.js bringing it's own engine (V8), which should be the same in your node.js and mine (both 0.6). What am I missing? Interesting that it doesn't fail for some...

Comment: so if they aren't allocated, how come that I get an out of memory exception?

Comment: @EasierSaidThanDone I don't know. Does it crash immediately?  Mine (even with the call to `.sort()` finishes right away. Are you on a 32-bit or 64-bit architecture?

Comment: A few points: a) you should determine where the code fails. Does it fail on `.sort()` or already on the line before that? b) You should keep in mind that V8 might try optimizing your code. Afaik sparse arrays should prevent it from doing any optimization on the array, but I might be wrong. V8 might actually try to allocate an actual array for optimization purposes. Try running node with V8 adaptive optimization turned off (`--opt false`). Also look at `man node` for additional optimization options.

Comment: Also note this snippet from the [MDN entry on sort](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort): `Specifies a function that defines the sort order. If omitted, the array is sorted lexicographically (in dictionary order) according to the string conversion of each element.`. `undefined` will most likely be transformed to an empty string, which will allocate memory.

Comment: --opt false doesn't change anything unfortunately.

Comment: Have you determined where the code crashes? Also, have you tried supplying a non default compare function to sort, that does not convert each value to it's string representation?

Comment: The sort crashes. I haven't tried another compare function. But I installed the latest node version and there it works...instantly

Comment: A petty, I really would have liked to know if this was caused by the default compare function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So in summary, **node.js does not allocate memory for undefined values in an array.** The crash I experienced must have been a glitch as no one else could reproduce it and installing the latest node.js version eliminated the problem for me as well.

Answer (score -3):

EDIT : Sorry for inexact, Might not be applicable to JAVA..
  Still might be helpful for someone who need it in other application.

An Array of reference is allocating  x

therefore  allocating    arr[100000] will allocate 100 kb x 4b ~= 0.5Mb (approximating)

and YES, definitely, if you ain't gonna use all the Array,
you should consider a HashMap which is a datastructure just for that..
HashMap is best in having a large search span with relative small amount of items.

Either way, there are solutions to allocate a small array, and expand it as needed, if needed.

Comment: No, JavaScript is not like other languages. Arrays are not preallocated. They essentially *are* hash maps.

Comment: I thought about Hashes, but I'd still be using integers as keys and I need to be able to sort them by key (or at least keep their order intact) and iterate over them sequentially. That sounds like a job for arrays rather than Hashes, doesn't it?

Comment: @EasierSaidThanDone what version of Node are you using? That code wworks fine for me (0.6.12)

Comment: " but I'd still be using integers as keys and I need to be able to sort them by key (or at least keep their order intact) and iterate over them sequentially. "  It's normal then to use an indexed hash.  Just keep each key in an array of size [number_of_keys].  Sort the array or keep the keys sorted as you store them.  At the same time build your hash of key/value pairs.